# How do I stash uncommitted changes in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Need some help on how I can shelve uncommited changes in a Git repository using Visual Studio 2013. I come from PHPStorm where you can shelve uncommited changes on one branch, switch to another and unshelve.

However, I can't find/see how this can be done in Visual Studio. Could someone shed some light on this issue?

Just to clarify why this may be needed: I might be working on branch X, and then figure that I am the wrong branch and I should be on branch Y. I need to shelve all changes from branch X, switch to branch Y, unshelve changes and then commit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `git` the concept you're looking for is `stash`. You add your changes as if you are going to commit them, and you then stash them with `git stash`. After changing branches, you can `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` (with the former leaving the stash available for reuse).

I'm familiar with the `shelf` concept from Perforce, which has a useful difference from Git's stash -- where you can send a shelf to the server and share it with other people, you cannot do that with git. However, with git you can just create a branch with the stash and push that to the server, allowing others to merge it where it's needed.

Microsoft does not provide a way to use this feature.

Comment: Is there some sort of way to do this using Microsoft's Git Provider plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with that plugin. I use git from the command line and through the SourceTree (on OS X, but a Win version exists) program. I would suggest looking in the same place you can commit and looking for a stash option there.

Comment: In my opinion this does not answer the OP question, which I would rephrase to: "How to do `git stash` in VS 2013 IDE". I'm also looking for it but came to the conclusion it is not supported (at least with VS 2013 Update 2).

I found also you can vote for it [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4576531-provide-stash-support-in-visual-studio-tools-for-g)

You can use this [guide](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/11/use-git-directly-from-visual-studio.html) to setup Package Manager Console to behave as git command line.

Comment: I don't know if this applies to VS 2013, but in VS 2017 you can go to "Team Explorer -> Branches -> Actions -> Open Command Prompt" and type `git stash` in there.

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 does not support shelving (called stashing in git)  for git repositories, but you can use 3rd party tools on the repository itself (I use SourceTree).

Comment: That you can use git tools on git repositories is not informative.  Suffice to say that despite virtually unlimited resources, Microsoft inexplicably gives you an impoverished git interface.  I can't image what technical difficulties would prevent that and suspect there are none.

Comment: How is it not informative to point someone to tools they may not have considered? Just because you're angry at Microsoft it doesn't mean my answer is wrong.

Comment: I agree with you @thelem

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I showed up late to this one.

I use TortoiseGit for this... It works really well and can work alongside Visual Studio as it is just an explorer plugin.

https://tortoisegit.org/

Comment: This is the solution of choice for GUI stashing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Stash to Visual Studio by using this extension: 
[GitStashExtension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vii.GitStashExtension)