# Am I missing something in VS 2013's Git support?

Tags: git, visual-studio

VS 2013 added "support" for Git but fairly basic Git functionality seems to be missing.

What I'd hoped was that Source Control Explorer could have alternate back ends (TFVC or Git) but what I find is that a few, coarse, high-level Git commands have been grafted onto Team Explorer.

- I can clone a repo
- I can create a local branch
- I can check in all the changes in a file

But among things I can't figure out how to do are:

- Stash changes (VS knows how to "shelve" in TFVC, surely this is a simple, parallel operation that happens to invoke `git stash`)
- Add some changes from a file (like `git add -- patch`)

I'd love to hear that I'm missing something.  Or is VS's support of Git really that weak? (I know you can install Git command line tools underneath VS but isn't the point of an IDE to keep you away from the command line?)

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161214/66519) as I do not think stash is supported as of Update 2 of Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: It's in the base 2013 distribution (I was on Update 1 and saw it) but I've since updated to Update 4 and it seems to have the same lack of features.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the Git support in VS2013 lack a lot features and is really basic.

There is no support for:

- stashing
- staging area (add chunck of files, all files are added by default instead of letting the user construct it's commit :( )
- rebase
- submodules (perhaps added for VS2015 --at least in TFS but not sure for VS2015--)
- viewing dag (but added for VS2015)
- ...

And I found it much more difficult to use than other GUI and really messy. As an descent git user, I am sometimes lost in their GUI, so I don't imagine for new git users :(
That's why I highly recommend to use an external tool until VS2015 is released and hoping that will usable...

But you could go and vote to [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio?query=git) to make it change...